# Русский язык. 8 класс. Приложение

Tags: приложение

Помогите пожалуйста с темой разобраться. Не могу понять, где приложение в 'стихи поэта Есенина' срочно

Answer (score 1):

При сочетании нарицательного и собственного имени (фамилии) человека приложением является имя нарицательное.
У вас приложением будет "поэта", а "Есенин" будет главным словом для приложения.